# NSLayoutAnchor - setting multiplier for XAnchor/YAnchor

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

How to set multiplier value using `NSLayoutAnchor`?

**For example**, we can use NSLayoutConstraint to do this with multiplier value of 1.5:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
view1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:view1];
NSLayoutConstraint *hConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view1
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view
                                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                             multiplier:1.5 constant:0.0f];
```

There is no multiplier parameter available when using `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor`

```
   hConstraint = [view1.centerYAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerYAnchor constant:0.0f];
```

Only constant value can be specified.

Comment: No iOS guys to help here!!!!

Comment: Your constraint is not active.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I have put only part of the code. I want to know how to specify the multiplier value using NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, as multiplier is only available for NSLayoutWidthAnchor and NSLayoutHeightAnchor.

Comment: I follow this [layout-anchors](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/pain-free-constraints-with-layout-anchors/) , Its always work for me, try it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two variation of that `NSLayoutAnchor` method that accept a multiplier but they're only available on `NSLayoutDimension` anchors (width and height):

```
func constraint(equalTo anchor: NSLayoutDimension, multiplier m: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint
func constraint(equalTo anchor: NSLayoutDimension, multiplier m: CGFloat, constant c: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint
```

For more info refer to [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutanchor).

Comment: Agreed. But, I wanted to know on NSLayoutXAxisAnchor as there is option to give it when we use [NSLayoutConstraint constraintwithItem] method

Comment: With `NSLayoutAnchor` there isn't. You'll have to use `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Answer (score 0):

If we count only equalTo Methods

1. NSLayoutAnchor has two methods

   - func constraint(equalTo: NSLayoutAnchor) -> NSLayoutConstraint;
   - func constraint(equalTo: NSLayoutAnchor, constant: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint;

Both two method are automatically from subclass of NSLayoutAnchor.

2.NSLayoutDimension has three methods.This class is subclass of NSLayoutAnchor

- func constraint(equalTo: NSLayoutDimension, multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint;
- func constraint(equalTo: NSLayoutDimension, multiplier: CGFloat, constant: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint;
- func constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint;

3.NSLayoutXAxisAnchor has only one equal methods,this class is subclass of NSLayoutAnchor

- func constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint;

4.Hence also, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor has only one equal methods,this class is subclass of NSLayoutAnchor

- func constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor, multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint;